# Sorting problem with 'query_posts' funcion in wordpress. Sort by custom field not working

Tags: query-posts, sort

0 down vote favorite

Hi, I am working with wordpress where i have a event listing system. There is a custom field in my post called starting_time which is unix timestamp. Now i want to short all posts by starting_time by this query_post command:

```
query_posts(array(
               'post_type' => 'event',
               'meta_key' => 'end_time',
               'meta_compare' =>'>=',
               'meta_value'=>time(),
               'order_by' => 'start_date',
             'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

But it not working. Here is the site http://citystir.com/events/. I am echoing the start_time in unix before the time remaining so you can see the value. And also my pagination is not working. May be i did something wrong in the query_post command.

Please someone response.

--------------------- Update -----------------

i have found a wonderful post here **kovshenin.com/archives/customize-posts-order-in-wordpress-via-custom-fields** but i didn't get it worked. May be for lack of my knowledge. Please take a look at it and let me know if you have any suggestions. I will continue working on that.

-------------------- Resolved -----------------

Changed order_by to orderby. And also i came to know that we can use meta key multiple times if we want it will not conflict. Here is the final code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'meta_key' => 'end_time',
'meta_compare' =>'>=',
'meta_value'=>time(),
'meta_key' => 'start_time',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'post_per_page' => '-1',
'order' => 'ASC',
'paged' => $paged
));
```

Thanks for all your hard work!

Comment: Please put your solution in new answer (yes, you can answer your own questions). Also I have doubts this is solution, because you most definitely can't have multiple array items with same key. It is not even WordPress, pure PHP - last value will overwrite earlier one. Check with `var_dump(array('meta_key' => 'end_time', 'meta_key' => 'start_time'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_by` doesn't take a name of the field, it takes type of order. Which for custom numeric field will be `orderby=meta_value_num`. But actual field used is taken from `meta_key` and you are already using it for filtering. See [Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters).

So you can't pull this of this easily at moment, not without filtering and modifying resulting SQL query. Upcoming WP 3.1 will have much more improved and flexible querying support for custom fields and it will likely be easier than.

Comment: Can i use standard SQL query by wp_query? How will be the query then?

Comment: @Sisir you can run raw query with [`$wpdb->query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database) method. For purpose of querying posts usually filters like `posts_where`, `posts_join`, etc are used. I didn't try anything that complex for custom fields myself so can't give you good example, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I will continue trying and updating here. Please take a look after one or two hours.

Comment: i have found a wonderful post here http://kovshenin.com/archives/customize-posts-order-in-wordpress-via-custom-fields but i didn't get it worked. My lack of my knowledge. Please take a look at it.

Comment: reffring to your first reply i used this code in my local version of the website not not worked either.$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'meta_key' => 'start_time', 'meta_compare' =>'>=', 'meta_value'=>time(), 'order_by' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged ));

Answer (score 1):

As for your pagination being broken--when you do a custom query_posts like this, it squashes any vars from the original query. If you want pagination to work, you have to explicitly pass in a "paged" var in the query args. Get the existing paged var like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Then add it to your query args:

```
'paged' => $paged
```