# Order by custom date field

Tags: custom-field, date

This one has been bugging me for a while. I've used Verve Meta Boxes plugin to add a date field to a custom post type I created, and I would like to somehow order by this field when using `query_posts` in PHP. What's the best way to do this? I haven't been able to figure out a way that didn't involve complicated custom queries.

Comment: one of my old days post.. check if it helps. Here i sorted by date saved in meta field http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/sorting-problem-with-query-posts-funcion-in-wordpress-sort-by-custom-field-not

Comment: Hello, I used this code: `'meta_key' => 'datum',
            
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            
                'order' => 'ASC'` since I assumed the compare things were meant for only displaying events that had not yet past. This still does not work, for some reason. It's very frustrating.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/sorting-problem-with-query-posts-funcion-in-wordpress-sort-by-custom-field-not Hello, Can you post your full code here so i can take a look? What is the `datum` value is it the unix time?

Comment: What is the format of your date field?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution:

```
SELECT wposts . *
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
            WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
            AND wpostmeta.meta_key =  'datum'
            AND wposts.post_type =  'optredens'
            AND wposts.post_status =  'publish'
            ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC
```

As other `query_posts()` methods / alternatives did not work very well.

Comment: Ideally you should always use WordPress functions whenever possible rather than directly querying via MySQL, as it protects you against future database structure changes & can utilise WordPress' in-built caching for speed/performance. What you are trying to achieve is perfectly possible with get_posts, query_posts or by filtering the main query.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see all of your code, without more context it's just shots in the dark. I use this to accomplish what you're trying to do, using date format `YYYY-MM-DD` and it absolutely ‘works for me’.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'datum',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $args );
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: I don't see why it's so much of a shot in the dark. I just have this meta field called `datum` (formatted properly YYYY-MM-DD through a custom date picker field), and other than that it's just a common wordpress query.

I guess the issue might be related to some conflicting plug-in (custom order or such) that tries to change the ordering to it's own.

Comment: @CookieMonster - it's a shot in the dark because you haven't posted the actual code you're using, just incomplete fragments.